# mod_ssl SSLRequire allow variable starting with underscore

Tags: regex, apache, mod-ssl

I am trying to enforce a rule so that only variables staring with underscore can authenticate a site.

1.Trying with SSLRequire  %{SSL_CLIENT_S_DN_CN} option(will take the client cert CN)

allow from all
                SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
                SSLRequireSSL

```
            SSLRequire  %{SSL_CLIENT_S_DN_CN} =~ ^_

            SSLVerifyClient require
            SSLVerifyDepth  5
            SSLUserName SSL_CLIENT_S_DN_CN
            RequestHeader set userid %{REMOTE_USER}s
```

Tried above but getting syntax error for       SSLRequire  %{SSL_CLIENT_S_DN_CN} =~ ^_

Comment: What is the motivation behind this rule?

Comment: allow only client cert  CN staring with underscore

Comment: I understand what you want to do, but why do you want to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Achieved this by below.

SSLRequire  %{SSL_CLIENT_S_DN_CN} =~ m#(^_)#